# CommonsMultipartResolver and spring session disturb each other

Tags: spring-boot, multipart, spring-session

There is the config of multi part config in spring boot

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(20480);
resolver.setMaxUploadSize(2048000000);
return resolver;
}
```

It is right and work successfully,when the below dependency is added

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

the below exception is raised:

> [ERROR]
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
>   Required request part 'file' is not present Required request part
>   'file' is not present

Where is wrong?

EDIT:
It is related controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/save"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST})
  @ResponseBody
  public FileProviderDto save(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String fileCode)
     throws IOException, SQLException
   {
```

Comment: add your controller and yourui codes for tracing the deatil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this config and work correctly.

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(20480);
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(2048000000);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

and skip MultipartAutoConfiguration.class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { MultipartAutoConfiguration.class })
```